# Angular Bootstrap - Default tab active (dynamic tab)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, directive

I have an issue with Angularjs Bootstrap Tabs. I want a dynamic tab to be active by default but it seems I can't as long as I have a static tab inside the same tabset.

```
<tabset ng-init="tab.active = true">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
        {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Static">
        Static
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

`

Here is a plunkr to explain :

http://plnkr.co/edit/DfM6r4tznE9b0K8LqvF0?p=preview

I want the "Dynamic Title 1" to be selected by default. Is it possible with the active directive or do I have to create a function which will handle the active state ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" ng-init="tab.active = $index === 0">
    {{tab.content}}
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Static">
    Static
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KQ33S5XUBld4QXc3q4Vj?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works perfectly. How did you find how to do it ? Directly in the directive code ?

Comment: Aww, new issue, it broke something. Now I can't change the active state from the controller ..

Plnkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/xV7OlVBkYYOv44IdsUHa?p=preview

Click on "New", the active state doesn't change to the tab newly created. If you take off the ng-init, it works. Any idea ?

Comment: Use $timeout to update the newly added tab. Updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9N4RMaasrG8stw37bHKH?p=preview

Comment: Wow thank you for your quick answer, it works ! I learned a lot here :)

Comment: Glad to help you. do upvote if it does help you.. :)

Comment: @daveoncode The library is indeed a turd. But, I think it's mostly because Angular itself is a cesspool.